# Adding signIn with google next-auth error client_id is required

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I am trying to add Sign in with google option in nextjs using next-auth, here is my [...nextauth].js file which is in api/auth folder:

```
        import NextAuth from "next-auth";
    import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

    export default NextAuth({
      providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
      ],
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    });
```

here is my app file in which i am also using i18n for translations:

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, session }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </I18nextProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

But i keep getting this error when signing in:

```
message: 'client_id is required'
```

here is the complete error:

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error client_id is required {
  error: {
    message: 'client_id is required',
    stack: 'TypeError: client_id is required\n' +
      '    at new BaseClient (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:185:13)\n' +
      '    at new Client (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1841:7)\n' +
      '    at openidClient (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:29:18)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async getAuthorizationUrl (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:70:18)\n' +
      '    at async Object.signin (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:38:24)\n' +
      '    at async AuthHandler (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:260:26)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthApiHandler (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:22:19)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuth._args$ (/Users/moeezramay/Desktop/job/moeezMatch/mosquematch/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:108:14)',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'client_id is required'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you're saying, there should not be any issue. Make sure to recheck your names which you're accessing from .env file. Also if you're using

```
.env
```

replace it with:

```
.env.local
```

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js 9.4 and higher, you can use the **NEXT_PUBLIC_** prefix in the **.env** file to make environment variables available to the browser. These variables will be replaced with their actual values at build time, so they can be accessed from your client-side code as if they were hard coded. For example, you can use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY` to access an environment variable called `API_KEY` that you have set.

Keep in mind that using this method will expose your environment variables to the client, so you should be careful about which variables you choose to make available in this way. You should only use this method for variables that are safe to be accessed from the client, such as publicly available API keys.

[next.js: Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)

**Non-NEXT_PUBLIC_** environment variables are **only available in the Node.js environment**, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser (the client runs in a different environment).

Comment: So should i make my variables like google secret key public? I dont understand what this has to do with the error, please explain.

Comment: @ShazibMahmood not necessarily, the error that your client do not see your env variable, if you are using your auth in client, then you should pass it as prop from server to client components and do not use it directly